# code sustitution

Tags: php, casting

can I replace

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

with this?

```
return (bool)$mail->Send();
```

regardless of what $mail->Send() is returning (it is a three party object)
**is there any type where (bool) acts diferent of the exclamation mark?**

Comment: You could also `return !!($mail->Send())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, and if it's not working you could do this: `return !!$mail->Send();`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to the following types is allowed:

> The casts allowed are:
>
> - (int), (integer) - cast to integer
> - (bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
> - (float), (double), (real) - cast to float
> - (string) - cast to string
> - (array) - cast to array
> - (object) - cast to object
> - (unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)

Otherwise, it's also possible to use

```
return !!$mail->Send();
```

however, that's not very obvious for someone else looking through your code in the future.

Comment: The reason for using the double-bang (`!!`) is to explicitly cast the return type of `$mail->Send()` to `bool`. Just thought I'd let you know :-)

Comment: I know - that was my original answer to his question ;)

Comment: Oh right. I just wanted to add a little explanation to those who don't necessarily know; there was a question about double-bangs here on SO a while back.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it like:

```
return $mail->Send() ? true : false;
```

Comment: Because this will return true if `$mail->Send()` fails, not false, which is more natural behaviour, as well as what the OP wants.

Comment: @Jam, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `return !$mail->Send() ? false : true;`?

Comment: You've edited your question since my first comment. What I meant was that if `$mail->Send()` returns a `false` value, putting the bang (`!`) before it inverts it's result, making the whole lot return `false` if `$mail->Send()` is true, and vice versa, which is counter-intuitive (right when wrong), and also not the behaviour the OP wants.

Comment: Oops, that was actually a typo!  Eek, I thought I typed `!!$mail-Send()`.  Then I thought about it and felt like the ternary format was a little bit more intentional for the future reader of the code.

Comment: I've had many a downvoted typo in my time. Speeling in code is more improtent than speeling in text, i fell ;-)

Comment: True story!  I'm glad the community uses the down-voting appropriately.  Thanks for "un-down-voting" :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your replacement works fine...

```
return (boolean)$mail->Send();
```

That if statement is written in a very strange way, the `!` mark is a logical `NOT` and simply reverses the bool, so it says...

if `$mail->Send()` is `NOT` true, return `false` otherwise return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the return-type of the Send() function is of the boolean type you can use this:

```
return $mail->Send();
```

Comment: I am not sure what $mail->Send() returns, I am rewritig a code example of a three party object and I want a bool.

Comment: Then use following to be sure the result is casted to a boolean:
    return !!$mail->Send();

Comment: @Luis I'd be wary of using anything you don't know the return type of.  Doesn't the 3rd-party code have documentation?